# Searching arabic with diacritics in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, arabic

So I have a huge database of Arabic written text with diacritics (diacritics are small characters in arabic that are attached to other characters)

e.g : with diacritic : وَهَكَذَا في كُلّ عَقْدٍ 
without diacritic    : وهكذا في كل عقد

I am using mysql and laravel to search through the text for a specific word that has no diacritics.

How can I ignore the diacritics in the search ?

It seems like smth like this works :

```
SELECT * FROM `LAWS` WHERE text = 'وهكذا في كل عقد'
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM `LAWS` WHERE text LIKE '%وهكذا في كل عقد%'
```

...

I am using utf8_unicode_ci and I tried some different collations, but none of them seems to work !

How can I make the LIKE statement in mysql work similar to the =  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use "utf8_general_ci" collation type of table 'LAWS' and also table fields collations change to "utf8_general_ci".

This should work with

```
SELECT * FROM `LAWS` WHERE text LIKE '%وهكذا في كل عقد%'
```

**2nd thing you need to manage the space between words of Arabic. You have the same text as you searching but different spaces between words.**

Like in DB

```
وهكذا  في  كل  عقد
```

But searching without or less spacing like

```
وهكذا في كل عقد
```

As smallest string you search will return better results.

[image: Sample image for Arabic query results]